# Do we have indepth NFC tutorial with code samples to identify and connect to Type A, Type B, and FeliCa technologies?

Tags: android, nfc

I would like to know the  answer for the following questions:

1. Identify device types (Type A , B or Felica)
2. Ways to open communication between the external POS
3. Code samples and how to test them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag type identification example:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
  Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG));
  if(NfcA.get(tag) != null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Type A tag found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  else if(NfcB.get(tag) != null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Type B tag found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  else if(NfcF.get(tag) != null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "FeliCa tag found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  else if(NfcV.get(tag) != null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "ISO15693 tag found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  else if(Ndef.get(tag) != null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Android Beam message received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  else
    Toast.makeText(this, "Unknown tag type!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // hypothetical...
```

}

There is no API defined in Android to communicate with an external reader. You could consider implementing peer-to-peer communication in the reader, using LLCP and SNEP (see [NFC Forum](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/) for the specs).